# Android Emulator black screens in VS 2017

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

The Android_Accelerated_x86_Nougat (Android 7.1 - API25) virtual device came preinstalled with my Xamarin install for Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.7.  I created a Cross Platform Xamarin.Forms application.  After the creation of all of the projects, I build the project and ran it in the default emulator that Visual Studio supplied me with.  This worked great!  For the first three times I ran my application.  Around the fourth or fifth time I tried to build my project, the emulator just black screened and nothing was on the display.

When I build my project now, I get an error message at the bottom saying this:

1>C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\TestingXamarin\TestingXamarin\TestingXamarin.Android\TestingXamarin.Android.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.

Could this be part of the problem?  If not it is definitely something that should be fixed.  Does anyone know how to update the version?  I've looked on many Xamarin forums and none of the solutions that other people have suggested have worked.

Comment: Do you check HAXM installer? ( in sdk tools)

Comment: I believe I do but what window do I go to to verify that?

Comment: Did you check the questions of others? like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539368/visual-studio-xamarin-emulator-black-screen

Comment: I did and none of the recommendations others suggested have worked for me.

Comment: What  about [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86030/targetframeworkversion-for-v7-0-targetframeworkversion-of-my-project-v6-0)? Can you show what have you searched?

Comment: I found a post this morning where I had to go to tools -> android -> android sdk manager, to download the 8.0 version.  That solved that issue but not my emulator black screen problem.